# How to extract numbers after text with a number with a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

With the regular expression

```
(\d+\.\d{2})
```

I extract numbers with 2 decimals from strings like

```
Ams1.74 Rot1.26 Lon1.28
```

The result would be

```
1.74 1.26 1.28
```

Now, I found out that strings AX1 and AX2 may also appear before the numbers, my question is then: how would I get

```
1.74 1.26 1.28
```

from the string

```
AX11.74 Rot1.26 AX21.28
```

with a regular expression?

Comment: How can one determine that `AX11` is supposed to be `AX1` and `1` and not `AX` and `11`. Becvause there are always 3 letters/digits in front of your actual number? Then use `(?<=\b\w{3})(\d+\.\d{2})`

Comment: When AX1 appears the 1 should not be included.

Comment: If there is always a number between 0 and 1 , and with 2 digit , simply use (\d{1}\.\d{2})

Comment: @SebastianProske A variant of your (?<=\b\w{3}) was what I needed. Thank you very much. ( Actual strings involved are more complicated, I simplified the question, but it works now. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you could use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!AX)\d+\.\d{2}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pQdgB8/1/).
Note, that backslashes need to be escaped, so you'd end up having:

```
(?<!AX)\\d+\.\\d{2}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this more complicated solution is accepted as the best answer?

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me for your example:

```
\d?\.\d{2}
```

Comment: And it does indeed !

Comment: @nilo de roock It doesn't, because if u have more the two digits in front of dot it won't match.